# How to solve this java path error from android Studio?

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_301.jdk/Contents/Home

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

After updating I got this type of error. I have reinstall jdk but same error.Please help

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_HOME typically the path to the java installation directory.

In your case, it should be upto Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_301.jdk
I assume .jdk is within name of the folder.

Comment: Can you please open a cmd prompt for the path you mentioned and run this command "java -version"? To make sure java is installed properly.